# Why won't PyCharm automatically refresh CSS output files when I am using an SCSS file watcher?

Tags: sass, pycharm

I have configured a PyCharm file watcher that transpiles SCSS (in a SCSS folder) into CSS (in a CSS folder). The CSS files appear to reflect the changes in the SCSS files only when I close and re-open the CSS folder dropdown.  How can I make this process automated?

This is what I have in the arguments field: 
`--no-cache --update $FileName$:$ProjectFileDir$/main/static/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css`

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If this answer has worked for you (which probably should since it worked for Intellij IDEA Ultimate) you should accept it (clicking the tick on its left side).

Answer (score 3):

The Output paths to refresh option is the directory that gets refreshed.  It needs to match the output directory you specified in the arguments field $ProjectFileDir$/main/static/css/

Comment: This worked just fine with IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.4, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

For future reference: I've published a post here on how to configure the file watcher with SCSS.

http://codeveloped.blogspot.nl/2015/01/pycharm-filewatcher-and-sass-scss.html

Answer (score 0):

1. console: gem install sass
2. console: gem install scss
3. console: gem install compass
4. console: which scss <--get the path
5. Pycharm: "Programm" set: path from 4. it could be /usr/local/bin/scss or usr/bin/scss
6. Pycharm: "Arguments" set: --no-cache --update  --force --sourcemap=none --compass $FileName$:$ProjectFileDir$/app-name/static/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css  ( be carefull using $Sourcepath variable  as mentioned before, it can return depending on the project multiple path path1:path2:path3 and scss do nothing)
7. Pycharm: "Output paths to refresh" set: $ProjectFileDir$/app-name/static/css/